# Is it possible to write a nested quantifier statement with predicate symbols inside?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was reading an example online and baffled myself. Suppose they set the domain to all living things. $G(x) = x$ is a grasshopper, $R(x,y) = x$ flies with $y$. Suppose they want the following transcribed into predicate logic: For every grasshopper, there is a grasshopper that flies with it. My first thought would be to declare the two domains for $x$ and $y$ like: domain of $x$: all grasshoppers, and domain of $y$: all grasshoppers. Yet, I believe it can also be written in such a way that the domain can be left as all living things. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this: $$\forall x(Gx\to \exists y (Gy\land Rxy)).$$

This reads:

> "For all living things $x$, if $x$ is a grasshopper then there exists a living thing $y$ such that $y$ is a grasshopper and $x$ flies with $y$."